# qt complex layouting (fixed size troubles)

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer

Hello i have troubles to make such layout.
Please help me.[image]

I tried to make such settings

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what is the designer screenshot good for - just to show you've been playing around?

Comment: It'd be simplest if you created your layout using code. It'd be very short and simple. What you need is to simply set fixed size policy on the widgets, precisely as you indicated on your mock-up. Use a grid layout, with the top widget spanning both columns. Show us some code - it must be a self-contained example, just the `main.cpp` file, one function. Edit your question when you've done it, and only **then** we can troubleshoot if it doesn't work.

Comment: Once you understand how to do it in code, it will be a trivial matter to do it using Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the next steps :

**Top widget**

- Set `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` `height` property to the same desired value
- Set `sizePolicy` property to fixed for the vertical option

**Bottom right widget**

- Set `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` `width` property to the same desired value
- Set `sizePolicy` property to fixed for the horizontal option

**Layouts**

- Add the bottom left and right widgets in a horizontal layout
- Use a vertical layout for the complete widget

Also check [how to use layouts with Qt Designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to QtDesigner, you may use one or both void QWidget::setFixedHeight(int h) and void QWidget::setFixedWidth(int w). These functions will "lock" just specified property, height or width.

[QWidget::setFixedHeight](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight)

[QWidget::setFixedWidth](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth)

Thanks.